# openmp ping pong breaks when using optimization

Tags: openmp

I have the following openmp program, compiled with mpicc -fopenmp -O0 ping_pong.c. On my machine executing ./a.out -N 10000000 typically gives "done in 1.22125 secs, m: 10000001". If I increase the level of optimization, the program hangs. Is there a way to 1) decrease the execution time while preserving the ping pong functionality? 2) make the code tolerant (no hang, not slower) of optimization?

```
#include <omp.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
 
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
  int num_threads = 2; 
  int N = 1000000; 
 
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) { 
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-N") == 0) { 
      N = atoi(argv[++i]); 
    } 
  } 
 
  omp_set_num_threads(num_threads); 
 
  int m = 0; 
 
  double t0 = omp_get_wtime(); 
  #pragma omp parallel 
  { 
    int id = omp_get_thread_num(); 
    while (m < N) { 
      if (id == 0) { 
        if (m % 2 == 0) m++; 
      } 
      if (id == 1) { 
        if (m % 2 == 1) m++; 
      } 
    } 
  } 
  double t = omp_get_wtime() - t0; 
  printf("done in %g secs, m: %d\n", t, m); 
}
```

Comment: It's not really a parallel code.  Sure, you've inserted a parallel pragma, but without a *work sharing construct* (such as a for loop) all that means is that a bunch of threads execute the same code.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark the code inside the `while` loop is OpenMP `sections` worksharing construct written explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I see that @HristoIliev, I suppose my previous comment might have been better expressed as *It's not really an OpenMP code ...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faster and fully optimizable, flush variable m before each if statement.

```
// to compile: gcc -fopenmp -O* ping_pong.c
// * can be 0, 1, 2, 3, or fast
// to run: ./a.out -N 10000000

#include <assert.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int num_threads = 2;
  int N = 1000000;

  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "-N") == 0) {
      N = atoi(argv[++i]);
    }
  }

  omp_set_num_threads(num_threads);

  int m = 0;

  int count0 = 0;
  int count1 = 0;
  int *arr0 = (int *)calloc(N / 2 + 2, sizeof(int));
  int *arr1 = (int *)calloc(N / 2 + 2, sizeof(int));

  double t0 = omp_get_wtime();
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    int id = omp_get_thread_num();
    if (id == 0) {
      printf("id %d reporting for duty!\n", id);
      while (m < N) {
        #pragma omp flush (m)
        if (m % 2 == 0) {
          arr0[count0] = m;
          m++;
          count0++;
        }
      }
    }
    else if (id == 1) {
      printf("id %d reporting for duty!\n", id);
      while (m < N) {
        #pragma omp flush (m)
        if (m % 2 == 1) {
          arr1[count1] = m;
          m++;
          count1++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  double t = omp_get_wtime() - t0;
  printf("done in %g secs, m: %d, count0: %d, count1: %d\n", t, m, count0, count1);

  for (int i = 1; i < N / 2; i++) {
    if (arr0[i] != arr0[i - 1] + 2) {
      printf("arr0[%d] = %d, arr0[%d] = %d\n", i, arr0[i], i - 1, arr0[i - 1]);
      assert(0);
    }
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < N / 2; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] != arr1[i - 1] + 2) {
      printf("arr1[%d] = %d, arr1[%d] = %d\n", i, arr1[i], i - 1, arr1[i - 1]);
      assert(0);
    }
  }

  printf("Both arrays are correctly formed.\n");

  free(arr0);
  free(arr1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Idiomatic OpenMP code would use the `sections` construct with two `section` blocks instead of `if (id == 0) { ... } else if (id == 1) { ... }`.

Comment: Surely there are races on m? (m is shared and m++ is not atomic).

Comment: @HristoIliev I think idiomatic OpenMP code would use `omp for schedule(dynamic)`:-)

Comment: @JimCownie, from my point of view, there aren't really races on `m` due to how the code works. Thread 0 only increments `m` if it is even. Once it does so, `m` becomes odd and thread 0 won't update it again before thread 1 runs and makes `m` even again. The repeated `flush(m)` makes sure that even if a thread misses the increment from the other thread in the current loop iteration, it will eventually flush its modifications and fetch the new value after one or more iterations.

Comment: @HristoIliev You are right, of course. From my POV it remains a weird piece of code, but maybe it's intended as an educational example, rather than something one would really want to do! (After all, if you really wanted this distribution of work, #pragma omp for schedule(static,1) would achieve it in a much more obvious manner).

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP's memory model allows for different threads to have temporarily diverging views of shared variables. On cache-coherent architectures such as x86, the most frequent reason for diverging views are register optimisations.

This is very much compiler-dependent, but with `-O0` most compilers don't do register optimisation, so both `if (m % 2 == 0)` and `m++` result in code that reads or writes the actual memory location of `m`. With `-O1` and higher, `m` is optimised to a register variable and the result is written back to memory only at the exit from the `while` loop. In the latter case, after one iteration, the register value of `m` in thread 0 becomes odd and the thread gets stuck. Similarly, the initial value of `m` in thread 1 is even (`0`) and that thread is already stuck.

Preventing register optimisation (and speculative execution / instruction reordering) from screwing the coherent view of shared variables is what the OpenMP `flush` construct is for. You need a bunch of `#pragma omp flush(m)` lines to make sure that both threads see the latest value of `m`.

You can also declare `m` as `volatile int m = 0`. The `volatile` modifier prevents register optimisation of `m`, so you'll get code similar to what `-O0` produces. This is not the same as using the OpenMP `flush` directive, since on x86 `flush` performs a memory fence too.